# How to make App_Data folder up to date in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-migration

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project, I had 4 different contexts, each one in a separate file, then I changed my plan and decided to create one file containing the 4 contexts.

When I did so, the `App_Data` folder still has the 4 previous contexts (files) with the extension `.mdf`, although I used migrations and brought my database up to data.

The second issue is that when I run any view I get a 404 error

> The resource cannot be found

although I updated all contexts in all controllers and recreated the views.

Here is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="HotelString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(localDb)\MSSQLLocalDb;Initial Catalog=HotelDb;Integrated Security=true" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and context is:

```
namespace HIMS.Context
{
    public class ModelsContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Reservation> reservations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CEO> ceo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ControlPanel> controlPanels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserAccount> userAccount { get; set; }

        public ModelsContext() : base("Name=HotelString") { }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions how to resolve those issues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue has been solved , i had to delete all controllers and recreate them.